# Animating UILabel Text Property with Interpolation

Tags: ios, animation, text, uilabel, nstimer

I want to animate the text property of a UILabel so that it looks like it counts from zero to a specific value (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7). I know that there is the possibility to achieve that with the help of NSTimer but is there a way to let the "animation" ease in and out with NSTimer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Using the `NSTimer` is the best way to do this.

Comment: Or using something like CADisplayLink, which will produce a smoother animation. But I think he's asking whether you can get an ease-in-ease-out effect with an NSTimer.

Comment: You have to implement easing yourself.

Comment: Is there a way I could observe keypath changes from core animation? I have a strokeEnd animation of a drawing and want to get the value changes of the strokeEnd and display it in a label (kind of like in a speedometer where a value increases with speed). I could not get it to work with KVO so I tried to use NSTimer but now I have the problem that both animations are out of synch because of the interpolation of the animation and the nstimer from the label.